# Concatenating elements from two arrays of same indexes

Tags: perl, concatenation

I am facing an issue while concatenating elements of indexes from two arrays.

Example:

```
 @x=(1,2,3,4);
 @y=(5,6,7,8);
```

I want to concatenate

```
$x[0]"_"$y[0]
```

Like this:

```
if @i=(..n), then $x[$i]"_"$y[$i]
```

Suggest the possible solution.

Comment: this $combined_array = array_combine($array1, $array2);
can concantinated two array

in your case u can write like this
$combined_array = array_combine($x, $y);

Comment: Do @x and @y have always the same length?

Comment: Why is this labeled with `regex` and `pattern-matching`?

Comment: Yes they will be. @PseftiS

Comment: can you tell me with an example @Arslan Ahmed

Comment: @ArslanAhmed : `array_combine` is a php function not perl.

Comment: I am using perl. Thanks@ArslanAhmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat the process for n elements in the array, you can do the following

```
my @x=(1,2,3,4);
my @y=(5,6,7,8);

my @concatenated_array=();
for my $i (0 .. $n)      # define $n <= min($#x,$#y)
{
  push @concatenated_array, $x[$i] ."_". $y[$i]; 
}
print "@concatenated_array\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can concatenate elements like this:

```
my @x=(1,2,3,4);
my @y=(5,6,7,8);

my $z = $x[0] . $y[0];
```

If you want use an underscore sign between two elements you can use like this:

```
my $z = $x[0] ."_". $y[0];
```

Comment: What if multiple elements are ther. I need to concatenate $x[1]."_".$y[1] and so on. Ican't enter like this for 1000 elements right? So, how to handle if i want to concatenate n elements from @x to n elements from @y? And i want to concatenate only elements of same indexes.

Comment: @Sam333 : Can you show us some real example and tell us what is the purpose to do that, I hope people here can give you better idea, if you will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In perl concatenation is done using `.` So if you want to concatenate two elements use

```
my $z = $x[0] . $y[0]
```

If you want to concatenate many elements with each other best is to do this in loop and keep on concatenating `$z` with element `$x[0] or $y[0]` and assigning it back to `$z`

```
my $z = $z . $x[0]
$z = $z . $y[0]
```

I do not know your exact condition on which you will be concatenating so i kind give you exact answer but if you use above logic with a loop i hope your problem will be solved.